# Why does my form add tabs to the data I send it?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $view="Mickey Mouse";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doOne(){
        document.getElementById("xyz").submit();
        }
    function doTwo(){
        document.getElementById("xyz").submit();
        }
</script>
<form class="xyz" id="xyz" method='POST' accept-charset="UTF-8" action='index.php'>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="60" name='article' id='article' WRAP=SOFT>
        <?php echo $view;?>
    </textarea>
<p>
    <button type="button" name='do1' id='do1' value="do 1" onclick="doOne()">do 1</button>
    <button type="button" name='do2' id='do2' value="do 2" onclick="doTwo()">do 2</button>
</p>
</form>

<?php
    var_dump("POST :",$_POST);
?>
```

When I run it, the form displays `[tab][tab]Mickey Mouse[tab]` instead of simply `Mickey Mouse`.  Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the space around < ? php echo $view; ?>

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" name='article' id='article' WRAP=SOFT><?php echo $view;?></textarea>
```

The textarea has no way of knowing whether those newlines and spaces are supposed to be part of the textarea content, so of course it includes them.